# Registering to receive notifications of remote CloudKit changes not working

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit, nsnotificationcenter

I have just finished setting up CoreData+CloudKit using the new iOS 13 `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. It works really nicely in that I can use auto-generated CoreData classes for property access and local storage, and the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` automatically synchronises changes between devices. The problem I am having is with getting notified of remote changes. I have checked the Apple documentation and this states that you tell the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`'s `NSPersistentStoreDescription` that you want it to send the notification, and then register other objects as observers of this notification. I have done this and added a test method to show when remote changes were detected. The alert generated by the test method is never generated, but if I kill the app and re-open it, the changes are there immediately. So I believe the remote changes are being synchronised and integrated into the local CoreData storage, but the notification is not working. I have added the `Background Modes` entitlement to my target and selected the `Remote notification` mode. Code is below. Any help would be gratefully received!

**Setting the option to send the notification:**

```
- (NSPersistentCloudKitContainer *)persistentContainer {
    // The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentCloudKitContainer alloc] initWithName:@"<redacted>"];
            [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // ...
                }
                else {
                    // ...

                    [storeDescription setOption:@(YES) forKey:NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey];

                    // ...
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    return _persistentContainer;
}
```

**Registering to receive the notification:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changes) name:NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification object:[CoreDataFunctions persistentContainer]];
}
```

**Test method to respond to changes:**

```
- (void)changes {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Changes received" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you access your app’s persistent CloudKit container to grab the `viewContext`, you need to set the `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` property to `true`.

```
lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    self.storeContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    return self.storeContainer.viewContext
}()
```

Making this one-line change will enable the app (which is supported by `NSFetchedResultsController`) to update the UI in response to remote data changes…

Comment: Yes that solved it - thank you!!! After enabling this option the notifications started firing and opening ViewControllers with updated content started showing information added on other devices. Thank you!!!!! I wish Apple's documentation on this stuff was better...

Answer (score 9):

You observed the persistent container instead of the store coordinator, it should be this:

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(persistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification:) name:NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification object:_persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator];
```